# Reference an element with a form value in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-applications, angularjs-directive

I have a complicated form with many fieldsets, and I want a select element that will move the selected fieldset to the top on-change. I'm new to angular and am having trouble trying to think about this angularly!

I've got my fieldsets, I'm writing my 'switcher' directive and populating it with the legends of the fieldsets on initialise, and have it console logging the title of the selected element, but I need the actual element so that I can move it up to the top of the list in the DOM. How can I associate the value of the select option with another html element? Or is there a better approach to this problem altogether?

My form:

```
<form>
  <switcher></switcher>
  <div class="switchable" ng-include="app/controls/outline"></div>
  <div class="switchable" ng-include="app/controls/labelling"></div>
  <div class="switchable" ng-include="app/controls/formatting"></div>
  <!--... etc...-->
</form>
```

An example include:

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>Outline</legend>
  <!--some form elements-->
</fieldset>
```

Switcher html:

```
<select ng-change="changeSwitch()" ng-model="selectedMenu"></select>
```

Switcher directive:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('switcher', function ($timeout) {

    return {
      templateUrl: 'app/directives/switcher/switcher.html',
      restrict: 'EA',
      replace: 'true',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var setOptions = function() {
          $('.switchable').each(function(i, ele){
            $(element).append('<option>'+$(ele).find('legend').text()+'</option>');
          });
        }
        $timeout(setOptions, 0);

        scope.changeSwitch = function() {
          console.log(scope.selectedMenu);
        }
      }
    };
  });
```

This prints the legend in the console on change, but I want it to move the corresponding div up to the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have control over fieldset elements, make them children of the switcher element.

```
`<switcher>
     <fieldset switcher-option="Outline">
         <legend>Outline</legend>
         <!--some form elements-->
     </fieldset>
</switcher>`
```

Next add custom directive to every fieldset that will log itself to switcher directive by requiring and using it's controller. Directives should not play with elements they don't own since it makes harder to understand from what place the change is coming from.
Here is a link to [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/KCy9GZYeXmkOAVlW1kpb?p=preview) where I did some modifications to your code and also added lots of comments to help you comprehend the changes since you've said you are new to angular.

Comment: Thank you - I had just started experimenting with the includes being inside and was wondering if actually the includes needed to be their own directives. I hadn't thought about making them attach themselves to the parent rather than the parent specifying them. I think I'm going to make the options an array so I can index them in the order they should be drawn - hopefully that will mean they get redrawn in order via the binding

Comment: If you want the order of fieldsets to match the order of options in the select element, what you need to do is to call the logging logic of switcher-option directive in **pre-link** function instead of **post-link** function(link is actually post-link). At the moment that logic is called in post-link, that's why the options are in reverse order.

Comment: It's the other way around - I want the order of the fieldsets to change. I figure I can do this 'angularly' if the options list is an array, ordered by index, then onChange I pop out the moved element, and put it at index 0 in the options. And have the switcher to be drawing out the fieldsets based on the order of the options. If that makes sense...

Comment: The switcher won't redraw the fieldsets based on the options array since the fieldsets, as for now, are "hardcoded" in the html. To make this work you need to use ng-repeat that will put the fieldsets in html while iterating over options.

Comment: I forgot to add that, except the point I made, I think your solution should work fine.

Comment: Not sure how to get a directive to then render an array of other directives, using an array...perhaps that requires a seperate SO question

Comment: I will try to modify the plnkr appropriately.